# SAP: RPTCORTMAIL doesn't send a mail

Tags: report, abap, sap-hr

I tried to use the Report RPTCORTMAIL but no matter what I choose no mail is send.

I chose a period and a person with errors but the protocol shows "0 mails send".

Even when I don't enter a person nothing happens.

While debugging I saw that the table PERNR_TAB_LANG is empty at the moment the receivers should be picked.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm thankful for every hint.

Comment: Try to tick "Log Display" and see what it shows for different time intervals. Maybe there is simply no correction to process.

Answer (score 0):

This report is used to tell employees to correct their errors from time evaluation (via IT2011). There are several reasons no employees are selected:
1) B1 Cluster timestamp is higher than last run of report (which means there no current errors to be sent)
2) There are no errors in B2 Cluster (check FEHLER table)

Comment: Hey I cant find table FEHLER :/
And where can I check the timestamp in Cluster B1?

Comment: Try report RPCLSTB2. Check table FEHLER and stucture BEZUG